# Scraping Hidden Table Values from a HTML

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, perl, screen-scraping

I am trying to learn web scraping and I am not getting anywhere with the meagre explanation on the websites. I code using perl and ruby, I wanted to scrape the values that arise from the javascript request that the page sends, there is a form on the website that takes in a query and there is a button that calls the js function
the table obtained is like this. Could anyone please help me with resources that could help me parse this data? I have been on it for more than a week now.

```
2012    11
2011    9
2010    12
2009    6
2008    6
2007    8


    <body>
      <div style="display: hidden">
      <form action="medsum.html" method="post" name="myform">
      <input type="hidden" name="query" value="il9"><input type="hidden" name="button"      value="tl">
     </form>
     </div>
     <!-- Start of StatCounter Code -->
       <script type="text/javascript">
     var sc_project=3474592;
    var sc_invisible=1; 
     var sc_partition=38; 
       var sc_security="008591cc"; 
      </script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.statcounter.com/counter            /counter_xhtml.js"></script><noscript><div class="statcounter"><a           href="http://www.statcounter.com/" target="_blank"><img class="statcounter" src="http://c39.statcounter.com/3474592/0/008591cc/1/" alt="blog stats"></a></div>     </noscript>
      <!-- End of StatCounter Code -->
         <script language="JavaScript">
      document.myform.submit();
      </script>
       </body>
```

Comment: Search for headless browser.

Comment: Sounds like there's an answer? Maybe this question could be answered, then?